# JTable: send key event to all selected components to check all selected checkboxes

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have `JTable` with checkboxes (because `getColumnClass` is `Boolean`).
User selects several rows, and clicks `space` but only "lead selection" checkbox gets `KeyEvent` and becomes checked.

How can I check all selected checkboxes?

It looks like a very simple task, but I can't find "official" way to do that, and I do not want to use hacks.

I can override `processKeyEvent` in my table and physically set `true` to all values in model, but it doesn't look good.

Comment: Define: *but it doesn't look good.*. A JTable is designed so that you can only edit a single cell at a time. Therefore what you want is outside the design of the JTable. Another option would be to add a KeyBinding to the JTable to handle the Spacebar. When the Action is invoked you iterate through the selected row and set the values in the model to `true`..

Comment: Can't you get all the selected rows using table.getSelectedRows() and then loop through the rows converting them into the model equivalents using table.convertRowIndexToModel(row)? Using these converted rows you could set the values inside your model to true.

Comment: @camickr I did not thing about the fact, that my idea violates JTable design. So, I used Action. Thank you

Comment: @JeanWillianS.J. thank you, that exactly what I did after all

Answer (score 2):

I followed @camickr and @Jean Willian S. J 's suggestion, and did:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class TableTest {
    private static final int CHECKBOX_COL = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> {
            var frame = new JFrame("TableTest");

            Object[][] data = {new Object[]{true, "Foo"}, new Object[]{false, "Buz"}};
            MyModel dm = new MyModel(data, new Object[]{"Enabled", "Name"});
            var table = new JTable(dm);
            var invertSelected = "InvertSelected";
            table.getInputMap().remove(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"));
            table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), invertSelected);
            table.getActionMap().put(invertSelected, new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    TableModel model = table.getModel();
                    for (int selectedRow : table.getSelectedRows()) {
                        var row = table.convertRowIndexToModel(selectedRow);
                        var value = !(Boolean) model.getValueAt(row, CHECKBOX_COL);
                        model.setValueAt(value, row, CHECKBOX_COL);
                    }
                }
            });
            table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

            frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

        });
    }

    private static class MyModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        public MyModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames) {
            super(data, columnNames);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return column == CHECKBOX_COL;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return (columnIndex == CHECKBOX_COL ? Boolean.class : String.class);
        }
    }

}
```

It now works. Thank you, everyone

Comment: (1+) Nice [mre].